# Problem overlapping two meshes for baking

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

So I'm fairly new to blender trying to figure how to bake meshes.

I've been following this [baking tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw&t=124s) and the first step is to hit ALT + G with your two meshes selected to overlap them (1:50 in the video).

The problem is my blender refuses to do this correctly, if you watch the video his meshes seem to be overlapped perfectly, whereas I get this result (Image below).

What am I doing wrong? Is it suppose to look like this? I've been trying to find a solution for hours so any help would be appreciated. I've reset the 3D cursor to the center of the grid and the origin to geometry for both objects.

[image: My two meshes after hitting Alt + G]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ALT+G** clears location of any mesh. so it brings mesh to origin(0,0,0).
similarly **Alt+s** to clear scale and **Alt+R** to clear rotation.

The two meshes are different, resulting different **center of masses** (**geometrical origins**) one of the meshs center of mass may be higher, so even if you clear location i.e set to origin they are not quite over-lapping.

In order to correct it, select all bottom vertices of anvil ( easy in wire mode ) **shft+s**-> **cursor to selection** then tab out to object mode shift+alt+cltr+c **change origin** to **3d curso**r. Do same for two meshes.

Then press Alt+G the should be overlapping. In fact Andrew specifically mentioned these in previous videos.